# Installing extension as non superuser on Amazon AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-extensions

I would like to allow non super users to install a specific postgres extension. Accordingly to the documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html that is possible if I set `superuser` to `false`  in the extension `.control` file.

However, in AWS RDS that is not possible, because I don't have access to the filesystem. Would there be a way to set those `.control` parameters via SQL query? Or did I reach the usability limit that RDS offers me?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon RDS has a custom list of allowed extensions. You can see it with:

```
SHOW rds.extensions;
```

[See online documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeaturesExtensions)

And you should do it as role `rds_superuser` or as a member of that role (actual superuser is not available). [Their website informs:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html)

> The `rds_superuser` role can do the following:
>
> - Add extensions that are available for use with Amazon RDS. [...]

Comment: So, let me see if I understood: in RDS ONLY rds_superuser  (or member of rds_superuser) can add an extension? (I know that they can do, but I would like to know if it's ever possible to do it as another user. If you can answer, beyond my upvote your answer gets the accepted answer).

Comment: @ribamar: *That* is up to Amazon's discretion. I can only tell you what they tell me and that it worked like that for me. But I don't know whether there are exceptions to the rule or whether that will change in the future.

Comment: thanks for you help, but i am keeping the question open while it is not fully answered.